# Tabs do not work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page in tabs that works fine, but it has a paging, I created an ajax to load the other tabs. But after I click the button, the tabs do not work

This is my function to create my tabs.

```
    var tabContainers = $('.messages');
    var navTab = $('div.list ul.nav li');

    function loadPage() {

        $(document).on('click', navTab, function(){
          var the_hash = $(this).children().attr('href');
          tabContainers.hide().filter(the_hash).show();

          $('div.list ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');

          return false;
      }).filter(':first').click();

    };
```

This is my ajax call

```
  //button
  var moreConversations = $('.btn-more-conversations');

  // more conversations
  moreConversations.click(function(){
    var currentPage = $(this).attr('current-page'),
        totalPages = parseInt($(this).attr('total-pages')),
        nextPage = parseInt(currentPage) + 1;


          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/inbox/" + nextPage
          }).done( function(data){
            if (nextPage == totalPages) {
              moreConversations.remove();
            }else{
              moreConversations.attr('current-page', nextPage);
            }
            insertConversations(data);
          }).fail( function(){
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Erro ao aplicar a paginação", "error");
          });

        });

  function insertConversations(page) {
    var content_nav = $(page).find('div.menu-conversations').html();
    var content_conv = $(page).find('div.content-conversations').html();
    $('div.menu-conversations').append(content_nav);
    $('div.content-conversations').append(content_conv);

 }
```

What am I forgetting? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Liam Is this http://jsfiddle.net/3EyCT/5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks @Liam This solved my problem to load the correct content, but the tabs stopped working, I changed my code above

Maybe is:
var the_hash = $(this).children().attr('href');

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on()` method instead of `.click()`. Since you are appending your `li` at run time, it will not attach `.click()` event to the future `li`. Hence in this case you can use `.on()` method.

```
function loadPage() {

  $(document).on('click', 'div.list ul.nav li' function () {
      var the_hash = $(this).children().attr('href');
      tabContainers.hide().filter(the_hash).show();

      $('div.list ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      return false;
  }).filter(':first').click();

};
```

Comment: why? that code is identical to `$('div.list ul.nav li').click`?

Comment: I have updated my answer @Liam, i know it is equivalent w.r.t click functionality, but `.click()` will not fire for the future elements. Well thanks for `-ve` vote.

Comment: @Liam, both code are not identical. This answer is telling to use event delegation so once new items inserted into `DOM` the registered event handlers will work.

Comment: So your delegating the event. Right, this was not clear. Maybe add an explaination next time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago. The solution is related with the fact that the AJAX call doesn't load the Javascript after your fail/success. In your `done` function add this code:

```
$.getScript('js/thenameofyourfile.js');
```

More info in:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/